# Cases in list with varying length in sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Given

```
t1 = {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {15, {}}, {16, {{0, 0, 4}}}, {17, {{0, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{0, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}}}
```

I want to exclude all elements where the second part is empty and also the sub-elements having at least one zero. So I would get

```
{{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}
```

I tried

```
Cases[t1, {d_, {{a_, b_, c_}}} /; a != 0 \[And] b != 0 \[And] c != 0]
```

But that excludes too many cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lst = {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {15, {}}, {16, {{0, 0, 4}}}, {17, {{0, 1, 4}, {2, 
     2, 3}}}, {18, {{0, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 3, 
     0}, {2, 3, 4}}}};
```

all elements where the second part is empty

```
lst /. {_, {}} :> Nothing
```

the sub-elements having at least one zero.

```
lst /. {a___, {___, 0, ___}, b___} :> {a, b};
```

make them together

```
r1 = {_, {}} :> Nothing;
r2 = {a___, {___, 0, ___}, b___} :> {a, b};
lst //. r2 /. r1
```

```
{{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Fold[DeleteCases[##, All] &][ t1, {{___, 0, ___}, {_, {}}}]
```

> ```
> {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}
> ```

Also

```
Cases[{a_, b : Except[{} | {{___, 0, ___} ..}]} :> {a, Select[FreeQ[0]] @ b}] @ t1
```

> ```
>  {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteCases[{_, {}}]@
  MapAt[DeleteCases[_List?(MemberQ[0])], t1, {All, 2}]

(* Out:
{{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}},
 {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, { u, {{2, 3, 4}}}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {15, {}}, {16, {{0, 0, 4}}},
      {17, {{0, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{0, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}},
      {u, {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}}};
```

---

A variant using `DeleteCases` and `Cases`:

```
Cases[DeleteCases[lst, {___, 0, ___}, ∞], Except[{_, {}}]]

(*{{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, {18, {{1, 1, 4}}}, {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{14, {{1, 2, 3}}},
   {15, {}},
   {16, {{0, 0, 4}}},
   {17, {{0, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 3}}},
   {18, {{0, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4}}},
   {u, {{1, 0, 2}, {2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}}};
```

via `Position`

```
p = Most /@ Position[list, {} | 0]
```

{{2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 1}, {5, 2,
1}, {6, 2, 1}, {6, 2, 2}}

```
Cases[{_, {__}}] @ Delete[p] @ list
```

returns

```
{{14, {{1, 2, 3}}}, 
 {17, {{2, 2, 3}}}, 
 {18, {{1, 1, 4}}},
 {u, {{2, 3, 4}}}}
```